# Iterate over a phrase to get fixed context without using padding

Tags: python

I'm trying to get for each word a fixed context (window_size) without using any type of padding.
For example:

```
sentence = ["hi", "my", "name", "is", "Francesco", "and", "i", "play", "drums"]

length = 9
window_size = 2
```

the window_size can varies from 1 to 5 and for each target word the context must have the same size.
In this example the desired output is:

```
[("hi", ["my","name","is","Francesco"]),("my", ["hi","name","is","Francesco"]),("name", ["hi","my","is","Francesco"]),
("is", ["my","name","Francesco", "and"]), ("Francesco", ["name","is","and","i"]),("and", ["is","Francesco","i","play"], ("i", ["Francesco","and","play","drums"]),("play", ["Francesco","and","i","drums"]),("drums", ["Francesco","and","i","play"])]
```

I'm getting stuck, maybe is it a recursive problem? Can someone help me?

```
import copy
values = []
word_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
possible = copy.deepcopy(word_ids)
popping = copy.deepcopy(word_ids)

boundary = 2

for index, num in enumerate(possible):
    popping.pop(index)
    
    values.append((num, popping[max(index - boundary -1 , 0):index + boundary + 1]))
    popping = copy.deepcopy(word_ids)

print(values)
```

Consider that boundary in the above code is the window_size

The code above print this:

```
[(1, [2, 3, 4]), (2, [1, 3, 4, 5]), (3, [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]), (4, [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]), (5, [2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]), (6, [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]), (7, [4, 5, 6, 8, 9]), (8, [5, 6, 7, 9]), (9, [6, 7, 8])]
```

as you can see the contexts haven't the same size

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you are trying to do. Could you add more examples? And if you have tried something, please add your code too (even if it doesn't work, but please state the incorrect output it gives you)

Comment: " In this example the output is..." - Is this really what you expect with `window-size = 2`? (Which, btw, is a syntax error. You can't use `-` in variable names, that means subtraction.)

Comment: Is the window size linked to the size of the second element and if so how? You have a window size of 2 but each list has 4 elements

Comment: The window_size is two because a target word that stays in the middle has two left context word and two right context word..indeed the problem came from the word on the side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to reduce and augment the windows sizes when you meet the edges:

```
import copy
values = []
word_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
possible = copy.deepcopy(word_ids)
length = len(word_ids)
window_left = 4
window_right = 4

for index, element in enumerate(word_ids):
  ctrl = True
  half = False
  if index >= length//2:
        half = True
  while (ctrl):
    if (index - window_left < 0) and half == False:
      window_left = window_left - 1
      window_right = window_right + 1

    elif half==True and (index + window_right  > length - 1):
      window_left = window_left + 1
      window_right = window_right - 1
    else:
      values.append((element, possible[max(0,index - window_left): index + window_right + 1 ]))
      window_right = 4
      window_left = 4
      ctrl = False  

# then remove the target word     
res = []
for element in values:
  element[1].remove(element[0])
  res.append((element[0], element[1]))
print(res)
```